# Замена содержимого тега div, содержимым другого html файла

Tags: html, jquery

Тренируюсь с сайтами и решил попробовать динамическую загрузку элементов, то есть у меня есть div и в нём отображаются данные: слайдер, текст, видео. При этом все они должны находиться в разных html файлах и что бы при нажатии на кнопки содержимое div'а менялось на соответствующее путем вытягивания этого элемента из html файла.

Как такое реализовать? Пока искал мне показалось что для этого подходить jQuery/Ajax, но я не нашёл как заменить содержимое тега содержимым другого html.

В HTML, CSS разбираюсь но не мастер, скорее любитель.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/MenuBarStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/SliderStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/AdaptabilityStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
        <li>
            <button onclick="LoadMainPage">На головну</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Новини</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Останні</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="CurentView">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider__wrapper">
            <div class="slider__items">
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="SliderImages/1.jpg" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="SliderImages/2.jpg" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="SliderImages/3.jpg" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="SliderImages/4.jpg" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="SliderImages/5.jpg" alt="c1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="slider__control slider__control_prev" href="#" role="button"></a>
        <a class="slider__control slider__control_next" href="#" role="button"></a>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
    function LoadMainPage() {
        $("#CurentView").load("jQuery/MainPage.html");
    }
</script>
</body>

<script>
    'use strict';
    var slideShow = (function () {
        return function (selector, config) {
            var
                _slider = document.querySelector(selector), // основный элемент блока
                _sliderContainer = _slider.querySelector('.slider__items'), // контейнер для .slider-item
                _sliderItems = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), // коллекция .slider-item
                _sliderControls = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), // элементы управления
                _currentPosition = 0, // позиция левого активного элемента
                _transformValue = 0, // значение транфсофрмации .slider_wrapper
                _transformStep = 100, // величина шага (для трансформации)
                _itemsArray = [], // массив элементов
                _timerId,
                _indicatorItems,
                _indicatorIndex = 0,
                _indicatorIndexMax = _sliderItems.length - 1,
                _stepTouch = 50,
                _config = {
                    isAutoplay: false, // автоматическая смена слайдов
                    directionAutoplay: 'next', // направление смены слайдов
                    delayAutoplay: 5000, // интервал между автоматической сменой слайдов
                    isPauseOnHover: true // устанавливать ли паузу при поднесении курсора к слайдеру
                };

            // настройка конфигурации слайдера в зависимости от полученных ключей
            for (var key in config) {
                if (key in _config) {
                    _config[key] = config[key];
                }
            }

            // наполнение массива _itemsArray
            for (var i = 0, length = _sliderItems.length; i < length; i++) {
                _itemsArray.push({item: _sliderItems[i], position: i, transform: 0});
            }

            // переменная position содержит методы с помощью которой можно получить минимальный и максимальный индекс элемента, а также соответствующему этому индексу позицию
            var position = {
                getItemIndex: function (mode) {
                    var index = 0;
                    for (var i = 0, length = _itemsArray.length; i < length; i++) {
                        if ((_itemsArray[i].position < _itemsArray[index].position && mode === 'min') || (_itemsArray[i].position > _itemsArray[index].position && mode === 'max')) {
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    return index;
                },
                getItemPosition: function (mode) {
                    return _itemsArray[position.getItemIndex(mode)].position;
                }
            };

            // функция, выполняющая смену слайда в указанном направлении
            var _move = function (direction) {
                var nextItem, currentIndicator = _indicatorIndex;
                ;
                if (direction === 'next') {
                    _currentPosition++;
                    if (_currentPosition > position.getItemPosition('max')) {
                        nextItem = position.getItemIndex('min');
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].position = position.getItemPosition('max') + 1;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].transform += _itemsArray.length * 100;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _itemsArray[nextItem].transform + '%)';
                    }
                    _transformValue -= _transformStep;
                    _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndex + 1;
                    if (_indicatorIndex > _indicatorIndexMax) {
                        _indicatorIndex = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    _currentPosition--;
                    if (_currentPosition < position.getItemPosition('min')) {
                        nextItem = position.getItemIndex('max');
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].position = position.getItemPosition('min') - 1;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].transform -= _itemsArray.length * 100;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _itemsArray[nextItem].transform + '%)';
                    }
                    _transformValue += _transformStep;
                    _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndex - 1;
                    if (_indicatorIndex < 0) {
                        _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndexMax;
                    }
                }
                _sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transformValue + '%)';
                _indicatorItems[currentIndicator].classList.remove('active');
                _indicatorItems[_indicatorIndex].classList.add('active');
            };

            // функция, осуществляющая переход к слайду по его порядковому номеру
            var _moveTo = function (index) {
                var i = 0, direction = (index > _indicatorIndex) ? 'next' : 'prev';
                while (index !== _indicatorIndex && i <= _indicatorIndexMax) {
                    _move(direction);
                    i++;
                }
            };

            // функция для запуска автоматической смены слайдов через промежутки времени
            var _startAutoplay = function () {
                if (!_config.isAutoplay) {
                    return;
                }
                _stopAutoplay();
                _timerId = setInterval(function () {
                    _move(_config.directionAutoplay);
                }, _config.delayAutoplay);
            };

            // функция, отключающая автоматическую смену слайдов
            var _stopAutoplay = function () {
                clearInterval(_timerId);
            };

            // функция, добавляющая индикаторы к слайдеру
            var _addIndicators = function () {
                var indicatorsContainer = document.createElement('ol');
                indicatorsContainer.classList.add('slider__indicators');
                for (var i = 0, length = _sliderItems.length; i < length; i++) {
                    var sliderIndicatorsItem = document.createElement('li');
                    if (i === 0) {
                        sliderIndicatorsItem.classList.add('active');
                    }
                    sliderIndicatorsItem.setAttribute("data-slide-to", i);
                    indicatorsContainer.appendChild(sliderIndicatorsItem);
                }
                _slider.appendChild(indicatorsContainer);
                _indicatorItems = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__indicators > li')
            };

            var _isTouchDevice = function () {
                return !!('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints);
            };

            // функция, осуществляющая установку обработчиков для событий
            var _setUpListeners = function () {
                var _startX = 0;
                if (_isTouchDevice()) {
                    _slider.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
                        _startX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
                        _startAutoplay();
                    });
                    _slider.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
                        var
                            _endX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX,
                            _deltaX = _endX - _startX;
                        if (_deltaX > _stepTouch) {
                            _move('prev');
                        } else if (_deltaX < -_stepTouch) {
                            _move('next');
                        }
                        _startAutoplay();
                    });
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0, length = _sliderControls.length; i < length; i++) {
                        _sliderControls[i].classList.add('slider__control_show');
                    }
                }
                _slider.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    if (e.target.classList.contains('slider__control')) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        _move(e.target.classList.contains('slider__control_next') ? 'next' : 'prev');
                        _startAutoplay();
                    } else if (e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to')) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        _moveTo(parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to')));
                        _startAutoplay();
                    }
                });
                document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
                    if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
                        _stopAutoplay();
                    } else {
                        _startAutoplay();
                    }
                }, false);
                if (_config.isPauseOnHover && _config.isAutoplay) {
                    _slider.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                        _stopAutoplay();
                    });
                    _slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                        _startAutoplay();
                    });
                }
            };

            // добавляем индикаторы к слайдеру
            _addIndicators();
            // установливаем обработчики для событий
            _setUpListeners();
            // запускаем автоматическую смену слайдов, если установлен соответствующий ключ
            _startAutoplay();

            return {
                // метод слайдера для перехода к следующему слайду
                next: function () {
                    _move('next');
                },
                // метод слайдера для перехода к предыдущему слайду
                left: function () {
                    _move('prev');
                },
                // метод отключающий автоматическую смену слайдов
                stop: function () {
                    _config.isAutoplay = false;
                    _stopAutoplay();
                },
                // метод запускающий автоматическую смену слайдов
                cycle: function () {
                    _config.isAutoplay = true;
                    _startAutoplay();
                }
            }
        }
    }());

    slideShow('.slider', {
        isAutoplay: true
    });
</script>
</html>
```

CSS 1:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
nav {background: #413F3C;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    /*position: sticky;*/
    /*top: 0;*/
    z-index: 3;
    alignment: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.topmenu{
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul,
.topmenu > li > button,
.topmenu > li > ul > li> button{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #282828;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
nav a,
nav input[type="button"]{
    text-decoration: none;

}
nav .topmenu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.topmenu > li{
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.topmenu > li > a,
.topmenu > li > button,
.topmenu > li > ul > li> button{
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FEFDFD;
}
.topmenu > li:hover,
.submenu a:hover,
.topmenu > li > button:hover,
.topmenu > li > ul > li> button:hover{
    background: deepskyblue;

}
.topmenu .fa,
.submenu .fa {
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: inherit;
}
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    min-width: 150px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.submenu li {position: relative;}
.submenu li a,
.topmenu > li > ul > li> button{
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background: #282828;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.submenu .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -1px;
}
nav li:hover > .submenu {

    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `$("#ID div Элемента").load("название файла html");`

Comment: @Denis640Kb, прописал в функцию
function LoadMainPage() {
         $("#CurentView").load("jQuery/MainPage.html");
     }
не работает, что я не так сделал?

UPD. jQuery/MainPage.html - путь, но думаю это ясно

Comment: Добавьте код и разметку в вопрос, чтобы можно было почему у Вас это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть ошибки в том, что Вы указали `onclick="LoadMainPage"` в то время, как необходимо указывать `onclick="LoadMainPage();"`

```html
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/MenuBarStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/SliderStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/AdaptabilityStyle.css">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        nav {background: #413F3C;
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            background: white;
            /*position: sticky;*/
            /*top: 0;*/
            z-index: 3;
            alignment: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .topmenu{
            text-align: center;
            list-style: none;
        }
        nav ul,
        .topmenu > li > button,
        .topmenu > li > ul > li> button{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            background: #282828;
            text-align: center;
        }
        nav ul:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }
        nav a,
        nav input[type="button"]{
            text-decoration: none;

        }
        nav .topmenu{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .topmenu > li{
            padding: 0;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }

        .topmenu > li > a,
        .topmenu > li > button,
        .topmenu > li > ul > li> button{
            border: 0;
            padding: 20px 30px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #FEFDFD;
        }
        .topmenu > li:hover,
        .submenu a:hover,
        .topmenu > li > button:hover,
        .topmenu > li > ul > li> button:hover{
            background: deepskyblue;

        }
        .topmenu .fa,
        .submenu .fa {
            margin-left: 5px;
            color: inherit;
        }
        .submenu {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 5;
            min-width: 150px;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .submenu li {position: relative;}
        .submenu li a,
        .topmenu > li > ul > li> button{
            border: 0;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            background: #282828;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        .submenu .submenu {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%;
            top: -1px;
        }
        nav li:hover > .submenu {

            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
        <li>
            <button onclick="LoadMainPage();">На головну</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Новини</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Останні</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="CurentView">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider__wrapper">
            <div class="slider__items">
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="21.png" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="21.png" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="21.png" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="21.png" alt="c1">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <img style="height: auto" class="img-fluid" src="21.png" alt="c1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="slider__control slider__control_prev" href="#" role="button"></a>
        <a class="slider__control slider__control_next" href="#" role="button"></a>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function LoadMainPage() {
        $('#CurentView').load("jQuery/MainPage.html");
    }
</script>
</body>

<script>
    'use strict';
    var slideShow = (function () {
        return function (selector, config) {
            var
                _slider = document.querySelector(selector), // основный элемент блока
                _sliderContainer = _slider.querySelector('.slider__items'), // контейнер для .slider-item
                _sliderItems = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), // коллекция .slider-item
                _sliderControls = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), // элементы управления
                _currentPosition = 0, // позиция левого активного элемента
                _transformValue = 0, // значение транфсофрмации .slider_wrapper
                _transformStep = 100, // величина шага (для трансформации)
                _itemsArray = [], // массив элементов
                _timerId,
                _indicatorItems,
                _indicatorIndex = 0,
                _indicatorIndexMax = _sliderItems.length - 1,
                _stepTouch = 50,
                _config = {
                    isAutoplay: false, // автоматическая смена слайдов
                    directionAutoplay: 'next', // направление смены слайдов
                    delayAutoplay: 5000, // интервал между автоматической сменой слайдов
                    isPauseOnHover: true // устанавливать ли паузу при поднесении курсора к слайдеру
                };

            // настройка конфигурации слайдера в зависимости от полученных ключей
            for (var key in config) {
                if (key in _config) {
                    _config[key] = config[key];
                }
            }

            // наполнение массива _itemsArray
            for (var i = 0, length = _sliderItems.length; i < length; i++) {
                _itemsArray.push({item: _sliderItems[i], position: i, transform: 0});
            }

            // переменная position содержит методы с помощью которой можно получить минимальный и максимальный индекс элемента, а также соответствующему этому индексу позицию
            var position = {
                getItemIndex: function (mode) {
                    var index = 0;
                    for (var i = 0, length = _itemsArray.length; i < length; i++) {
                        if ((_itemsArray[i].position < _itemsArray[index].position && mode === 'min') || (_itemsArray[i].position > _itemsArray[index].position && mode === 'max')) {
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    return index;
                },
                getItemPosition: function (mode) {
                    return _itemsArray[position.getItemIndex(mode)].position;
                }
            };

            // функция, выполняющая смену слайда в указанном направлении
            var _move = function (direction) {
                var nextItem, currentIndicator = _indicatorIndex;
                ;
                if (direction === 'next') {
                    _currentPosition++;
                    if (_currentPosition > position.getItemPosition('max')) {
                        nextItem = position.getItemIndex('min');
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].position = position.getItemPosition('max') + 1;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].transform += _itemsArray.length * 100;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _itemsArray[nextItem].transform + '%)';
                    }
                    _transformValue -= _transformStep;
                    _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndex + 1;
                    if (_indicatorIndex > _indicatorIndexMax) {
                        _indicatorIndex = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    _currentPosition--;
                    if (_currentPosition < position.getItemPosition('min')) {
                        nextItem = position.getItemIndex('max');
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].position = position.getItemPosition('min') - 1;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].transform -= _itemsArray.length * 100;
                        _itemsArray[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _itemsArray[nextItem].transform + '%)';
                    }
                    _transformValue += _transformStep;
                    _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndex - 1;
                    if (_indicatorIndex < 0) {
                        _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndexMax;
                    }
                }
                _sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transformValue + '%)';
                _indicatorItems[currentIndicator].classList.remove('active');
                _indicatorItems[_indicatorIndex].classList.add('active');
            };

            // функция, осуществляющая переход к слайду по его порядковому номеру
            var _moveTo = function (index) {
                var i = 0, direction = (index > _indicatorIndex) ? 'next' : 'prev';
                while (index !== _indicatorIndex && i <= _indicatorIndexMax) {
                    _move(direction);
                    i++;
                }
            };

            // функция для запуска автоматической смены слайдов через промежутки времени
            var _startAutoplay = function () {
                if (!_config.isAutoplay) {
                    return;
                }
                _stopAutoplay();
                _timerId = setInterval(function () {
                    _move(_config.directionAutoplay);
                }, _config.delayAutoplay);
            };

            // функция, отключающая автоматическую смену слайдов
            var _stopAutoplay = function () {
                clearInterval(_timerId);
            };

            // функция, добавляющая индикаторы к слайдеру
            var _addIndicators = function () {
                var indicatorsContainer = document.createElement('ol');
                indicatorsContainer.classList.add('slider__indicators');
                for (var i = 0, length = _sliderItems.length; i < length; i++) {
                    var sliderIndicatorsItem = document.createElement('li');
                    if (i === 0) {
                        sliderIndicatorsItem.classList.add('active');
                    }
                    sliderIndicatorsItem.setAttribute("data-slide-to", i);
                    indicatorsContainer.appendChild(sliderIndicatorsItem);
                }
                _slider.appendChild(indicatorsContainer);
                _indicatorItems = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__indicators > li')
            };

            var _isTouchDevice = function () {
                return !!('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints);
            };

            // функция, осуществляющая установку обработчиков для событий
            var _setUpListeners = function () {
                var _startX = 0;
                if (_isTouchDevice()) {
                    _slider.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
                        _startX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
                        _startAutoplay();
                    });
                    _slider.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
                        var
                            _endX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX,
                            _deltaX = _endX - _startX;
                        if (_deltaX > _stepTouch) {
                            _move('prev');
                        } else if (_deltaX < -_stepTouch) {
                            _move('next');
                        }
                        _startAutoplay();
                    });
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0, length = _sliderControls.length; i < length; i++) {
                        _sliderControls[i].classList.add('slider__control_show');
                    }
                }
                _slider.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    if (e.target.classList.contains('slider__control')) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        _move(e.target.classList.contains('slider__control_next') ? 'next' : 'prev');
                        _startAutoplay();
                    } else if (e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to')) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        _moveTo(parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to')));
                        _startAutoplay();
                    }
                });
                document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
                    if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
                        _stopAutoplay();
                    } else {
                        _startAutoplay();
                    }
                }, false);
                if (_config.isPauseOnHover && _config.isAutoplay) {
                    _slider.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                        _stopAutoplay();
                    });
                    _slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                        _startAutoplay();
                    });
                }
            };

            // добавляем индикаторы к слайдеру
            _addIndicators();
            // установливаем обработчики для событий
            _setUpListeners();
            // запускаем автоматическую смену слайдов, если установлен соответствующий ключ
            _startAutoplay();

            return {
                // метод слайдера для перехода к следующему слайду
                next: function () {
                    _move('next');
                },
                // метод слайдера для перехода к предыдущему слайду
                left: function () {
                    _move('prev');
                },
                // метод отключающий автоматическую смену слайдов
                stop: function () {
                    _config.isAutoplay = false;
                    _stopAutoplay();
                },
                // метод запускающий автоматическую смену слайдов
                cycle: function () {
                    _config.isAutoplay = true;
                    _startAutoplay();
                }
            }
        }
    }());

    slideShow('.slider', {
        isAutoplay: true
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Убейте меня, мне стыдно...

Comment: А что делает эта строчка <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>?

Comment: @DiDra всё нормально, опечатки бывают )

Comment: @DiDra подключает библиотеку jquery через cdn(https://code.jquery.com/) . Но у Вас она установлена локально. Можете использовать свою.

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Comment: @DiDra рад помочь ) Вы на правильном пути, так держать )